# Can I make a WPF DataGridRow unselectable?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, triggers, styles

I have a style on my datagrid to disable a DataGridRow based on a property binding.  This makes the row unselectable, which is what I want.  However, I am still able to select the disabled rows using at least 2 other ways.  The first is if I use a dragging motion between two enabled rows that surround the disabled row.  The second is if I click on the "select all" button on the top left of the datagrid.  Is there a way to make specific rows completely unselectable?

This is what I currently have:

```
  <DataGrid.RowStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
          <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DisableMe}" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
              </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
  </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using the SelectionChanged event to undo the selection? I really don't think there is a straightforward way to it, anyway.

You could also change the row style so it appears unselected even if it IS selected, and filter it out the selection through code...

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon this thread with the same problem, and I want to point out that you can simply set enabled to false.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think of any proper solution to this question. But as a workaround you can bind 'IsHitTestVisible' property of DataGrid to 'IsEnabled'.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource   Self},Path=IsEnabled}"/>
          <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DisableMe}" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
              </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```